# why i got this php error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['

Tags: php, syntax

can you tell me please, where is problem? Why i got this php error: *Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['*

using this code:

```
<?php

$x=new Sklonovani();
$tvary=$x->Sklonuj('Praha'[, $zivtone=false[, $preferovanyRod='2']]);   


?>
```

Comment: Looks like you just copied the syntax from some documentation, where the `[ … ]` typically denote optional portions of code.

Comment: the square brackets are to denote optional parameters of a function, you're not supposed to actually type them.

Answer (score 2):

The `[` and `]` in the parameter list mean those parameters are optional.

```
$x=new Sklonovani();
$tvary=$x->Sklonuj('Praha', false, '2');
```

For example:

```
$tvary=$x->Sklonuj('Praha'[, $zivtone=false[, $preferovanyRod='2']]);
```

`$zivtone` and `$preferovanyRod` do not need to be passed into the method in order for it to run. Without seeing the actual code where this is define, it looks like `$zitvone` will default to `false` and `$preferovanyRod` will default to `'2'` if you don't pass values for those.

Comment: why do you specify the optional parameters?

Comment: Because its actualy incorrect. Remove the var assignments otherwise true will be passed to the function

Comment: @DarkBee: incorrect. it's just a var assignment. it won't turn into true.

Comment: @Adelphia Yup. I was confused with `if($var = 1) {}`

Comment: @DarkBee: no strange behavior there. if you're confused, post a question ;)

Comment: @DarkBee anything you put in an `if` will naturally evaluate to true or false.